# exponential/logarithm for unipotent algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, matrix-exponential

Let $k$ be a field (of possibly positive characteristic), let $U_n$ denote the space of all $n \times n$ unipotent upper triangular matrices over $k$, and let $G$ be an algebraic subgroup of $U_n$ (hence a unipotent algebraic group itself).  Then each $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$ (thought of as a member of $\text{Lie}(U_n)$, i.e. a strictly upper triangular $n \times n$ matrix) is nilpotent, so it makes sense to define

$\text{exp}(X) = 1 + X + X^2/2! + \dots + X^{n-1}/(n-1)!$

(This definition makes sense even in characteristic $p > 0$ so long as $p \geq n$, i.e. so that $p$ never divides $1!, 2!, \dots, (n-1)!$).  We can also define, for $g \in G$,
since $g-1$ is nilpotent,

$\log(g) =  (g-1) - (g-1)^2/2 + (g-1)^3/3 - \dots \pm (g-1)^{n-1}/(n-1) $

Obviously $\text{exp}$ and $\log$ define maps from $\text{Lie}(U_n)$ to $U_n$ and back to $\text{Lie}(U_n)$, and are bijective, being inverses of one another.

**My Question**: If $g \in G$, is $\log(g) \in \text{Lie}(G)$?  Or, equivalently, for $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$, is $\text{exp}(X) \in G$?

I feel like there should be an obvious proof of this, but I don't see it.  If $G$ were a Lie group, the Lie algebra of $G$ would often just be defined to
be all $X$ such that $e^{tX} \in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and so for Lie groups $\text{exp}$ maps from $\text{Lie}(G)$ to $G$ simply by definition.  In the algebraic group context this definition no longer makes sense generally, and even when it does, is not used in the literature (so far as I've seen),
so I tried using each of the following equivalent definitions of $\text{Lie}(G)$, with no success:

- $\text{Lie}(G) = \text{Dist}_1^+(G)$ (distributions of order no greater than $1$ without constant term)
- $\text{Lie}(G) = $ the subspace of $\text{Lie}(U_n) = \text{Dist}_1^+(U_n)$ which kills $I = (\text{defining polynomials of $G$})$
- $\text{Lie}(G) = \{M \in \text{Lie}(U_n): 1 + \tau M \in G(k[\tau]) \}$ where $\tau^2 = 0$
- $\text{Lie}(G) = \{M \in \text{Lie}(U_n) : 1 + \tau M \text{ satisfies the defining polynomials of } G  \}$, again where $\tau^2 = 0$
- $\text{Lie}(G) = $ left invariant derivations on the Hopf algebra of $G$

It is certainly believable on it's face; we have that $\text{Lie}(G) \stackrel{\text{exp}}{\longrightarrow} U_n \stackrel{\log}{\longrightarrow} \text{Lie}(G)$
composes to the identity, similarly for $G \stackrel{\log}{\longrightarrow} \text{Lie}(U_n) \stackrel{\text{exp}}{\longrightarrow} G$, but I don't see why in the
meantime that $\log(G) \subset \text{Lie}(G)$ or that $\text{exp}(\text{Lie}(G)) \subset G$.

If it makes a difference, I'm actually only interested in the case where the defining polynomials of $G$ have integer (perhaps mod $p$) coefficients.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**: Here's a more basic question, one which might help answer the above.

Suppose $k = \mathbb{R}$.  Then $G$ is also a Lie group, and it is customary to define

$\text{Lie}(G) = \{ X \in \text{Lie}(U_n): e^{tX} \in G \text{ for all } t \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Can someone explain, or point me to a reference explaining, why this definition is equivalent to any of the above definitions for $\text{Lie}(G)$ as an algebraic group?

Comment: "unipotent group, hence a subgroup of $U_n$" is not very well-said: you're making a choice of $n$ and embedding into $U_n$. In other words, it's fine to start with a closed subgroup $G$ of $U_n$ and proceed; what follows does not only depend on the isomorphism class of $G$ (notably the fact that $n$ exceeds the characteristic ought to play a role).

Comment: Good point YCor, thank you.  I've reworded the question.

Comment: You're using intrinsic definitions of $Lie(G)$, but $G$ being embedded into an affine space (the space of matrices), you could use, as a definition, the definition of its Zariski tangent subspace of the subvariety $G$ at $I_n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula ensures that exp(Lie algebra) is some group  and vice versa log(group) = Lie algebra, so in sense that is one of the ways to define Lie group<->algebra correspondence,   it seems you wanna try to prove that "some" group would be exactly the group you started with , is it correct ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.  And I've verified that, in either characteristic zero, or when $\text{char}(k) = p \geq n$, the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula works just as well in the algebraic group context as in the Lie group context, so $\text{exp}(\text{Lie}(G))$ is definitely a group.  I just don't know if it's actually $G$.

Comment: Over $k=\mathbb R$ or $k=\mathbb C$ it is easy. You define ${\rm Lie}(G)$ as the tangent space to $G$ at 1. Then you define a map $E\colon k\to G$ by the differential equation  $\frac{d}{dt} E(t)=X\cdot E(t)$ with $E(0)=1$. From the theory of ordinary differential equations it follows that such a map $E$ exists and is unique.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any of that machinery (differential equations) over arbitrary fields $k$.

Comment: (cont.) Now this map $E$ is a solutions of the "same" differential equation in $U_n$, and the map $t\mapsto {\rm exp}(tX)$ is a solution of the same differential equation with the same initial condition. From the uniqueness theorem for the ordinary differential equations it follows $E(t)={\rm exp}(tX)$ for all $t\in k$, in particular, for $t=1$. Thus $E(1)={\rm exp}(X)$. We conclude that ${\rm exp}(X)\in G$.

Comment: Over a field of characteristic 0 we have the Lefschetz principle, which reduces the question to the case $k=\mathbb C$.

Comment: (cont.) Namely, we may assume that $G$ and $X$ are defined over a field $K$ that is finitely generated over $\mathbb Q$, and we embed $K$ into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: By induction, the result is true for the derived subgroup of $G$.  I'm not immediately sure how to handle the step from the derived subgroup to $G$ itself, but perhaps it's less daunting (since the quotient is unipotent Abelian).

Comment: (Or, which perhaps makes it even easier, one could consider one of the filtrations of $U_n$ by normal subgroups for which successive quotients are $\mathfrak{gl}_1$s, so that its intersection with $G$ is a filtration whose successive quotients are subgroups of $\mathfrak{gl}_1$, and again proceed by induction—somehow.)

Comment: Mikhail - Thanks for the comment.  I agree that that's a good way to see the result for $k = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  I'm not very familiar with the Lefshetz principle, but as I understand it it only applies when the field $k$ is of characteristic zero and algebraically closed.  I'm not able to assume either of these in my case (indeed, I'm more interested in positive characteristic).

Comment: @MikeCrumley, the algebraically closed assumption is not an issue, because the problem is insensitive to base change (it holds over $\overline k$ if and only if it holds over $k$).

Comment: You indicate in several comments ([e.g.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326810/exponential-logarithm-for-unipotent-algebraic-groups/327519#comment816880_326852)) that this is meant to be part of an upcoming paper.  Is that paper now available?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, but unpublished as of yet.  The finished manuscript can be found in the below link (it's sitting in my Github for now).  Mikhail's contribution, the subject under discussion, can be found in the appendix.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikecrumley/Publications/master/Positive%20Characteristic%20Representations%20and%20Distribution%20Algebras%20of%20Certain%20Unipotent%20Algebraic%20Groups_Mike%20Crumley.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is false in characteristic $p$, no matter how large $p$ is. The counterexample is the group parameterized by

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t & t^p \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Its Lie algebra is generated by the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

whose exponential does not lie in the group.

Comment: Yes that definitely settles it.  Thank you for catching this Will.

Comment: Assume that over group $G$ over a field $k$ of a characteristic $p$ is the reduction module $p$ of a smooth group scheme $\mathfrak G$ over the Witt ring $O=W(k)$, such that ${\rm Lie}(G)$ is the reduction modulo $p$ of ${\rm Lie}(\mathfrak G)$. Assume that our nilpotent matrix $X$ in ${\rm Lie}(G)$  lifts to a nilpotent matrix $X_O$ in  ${\rm Lie}(\mathfrak G)$. Is it possible to prove that $\exp_{<p}(X)\in G(k)$ because it is the reduction of $\exp(X_O)\in \mathfrak G(O)$ ?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Yes, that works, by exactly the argument you state, as long as we still assume $p>n$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Good, but what do you mean by "exactly by the argument you state"? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @WillSawin: Even though I write "a smooth group scheme $\mathfrak G$ over the Witt ring", I do not understand what a "smooth group scheme" means. Where can I read about this?

Comment: @MikhaiBorovoi Just a couple thoughts.  Will's counterexample is in fact a counterexample to several other "nice" properties of unipotent groups in positive characteristic that I had conjectured (relating to their distribution algebras).  The problem obviously is the the presence of a "Frobenius twist", i.e. the $t^p$ term.  This seems to me to be irreparable and illustrates why postive characteristic unipotent groups are so nasty in general.

Comment: (cont.) But, if we could place conditions on a unipotent group so that counterexamples such as Will's are ruled out, I think the rest of the results will go through (for whatever it turns out to be worth).

Comment: (cont.) For example, the conjecture is obviously true for the group

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & y \\ 0 & 1 & x \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

in characteristic $p > 3$, because you don't get that Frobenius garbage.  If we were able to state in formal terms how to rule out examples such as Will's, and if I can verify that my other conjectures are true for such groups, some of this might be worth something.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: you can read about smooth group schemes in section 11.6 of "Introduction to Affine Group Schemes" (Waterhouse), and proposition 7.17 of "Representations of Algebraic Groups" (Jantzen).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi linked me to this nice counterexample from a [question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368659).  It elegantly saved me from a wrong argument that I was about to try, which was to use, not the exponential map, but the Cayley transform when $p \ne 2$—basically the same counterexample, trivially changed to lie in an orthogonal group, works.  Thank you!  (For grudging values of "thanks".)

Comment: @MikeCrumley, unfortunately (for these purposes) [those references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326810/exponential-logarithm-for-unipotent-algebraic-groups/336500#comment818313_327519) are, I think exclusively, about smooth group schemes over *fields*, whereas I think @‍MikhailBorovoi's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326810/exponential-logarithm-for-unipotent-algebraic-groups/336500#comment817979_327519) was about smooth group schemes over *rings* (specifically, the Witt-vector ring).

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: I roll back to the previous proof, in characteristic 0 only. My last proof including characteristic $p$ was false (thanks to Will Sawin for noticing this).

Let $G={\rm GL}_{n,k}$\,, where $k$ is a field of characteristic 0. 
Consider the formal power series
$$\exp(x)=1 + x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\dots$$
over ${\mathbb{Q}}$ and the polynomial
$$\exp_{<n}(x)=1+x+\dots+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1},$$
which is defined also in characteristic $p\ge n$.

> **Theorem 1.** *Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0.
>    Let $H\subset G={\rm GL}_{n,k}$ be an algebraic subgroup defined over $k$.
>   Let $X\in{\rm Lie}(H)\subset{\mathfrak{gl}}_{n,k} = M_n(k)$ be a* **nilpotent** *matrix. Then
>   $\exp_{<n}(X)\in H(k)$.*

Note that since $X\in M_n(k)$ is nilpotent, we have $X^n=0$.

The version of Theorem 1 in positive characteristic is false, see the answer of Will Sawin.

Set $V=k^n$. Write 
$$T^{ij}(V)=V\otimes\dots\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes\dots\otimes V^*$$ ($i$ times $V$, $j$ times $V^*$), where $V^*$ is the dual space to $V$, and set
$$W=W^{\le N}=\bigoplus_{0\le i,j\le N} T^{ij}(V).$$
Let $\theta=\theta^{\le N}$ denote the natural representation of $G={\rm GL}(V)$ in $W$, and let $d\theta$ denote the corresponding
representation of ${\rm Lie}(G)={\mathfrak{gl}}(V)$ in $W$.
Since $X$ is nilpotent and $\theta\colon {\rm GL}(V)\to {\rm GL}(W)$ is a homomorphism of linear algebraic groups,
the linear operator $(d\theta)(X)\in{\rm End}(W)$ is nilpotent; see  Springer, Linear Algebraic Groups (2nd ed.), Theorem 4.4.20.
Note that in general it is not true that $((d\theta)(X))^n=0$, but one can show that $((d\theta)(X))^{2nN}=0$.

> **Theorem 2.** *Assume that ${\rm char}(k)=0$.
>   Then for any* **nilpotent** *matrix $X\in {\rm End}(V)={\mathfrak{gl}}(V)$
>   we have* 
>   $$\exp((d\theta)(X))=\theta(\exp(X)).$$

Note that $\theta(\exp(X))$ and $\exp((d\theta)(X))$ are defined
because both $X\in {\rm End}(V)$ and $(d\theta)(X)\in{\rm End}(W)$
are nilpotent operators and because ${\rm char}(k)=0$.

We deduce Theorem 1 from Theorem 2. There exists a natural number $N=N_H$ and a tensor $t=t_H\in W=W^{\le N}$
such that $H$ is the stabilizer in $G$ of the line $k\cdot t\subset W$ with respect to $\theta$
and such that ${\rm Lie}(H)$ is the stabilizer in ${\rm Lie} (G)$ of  this line with respect to $d\theta$;
see Springer's book, Lemmas 5.5.1 and 5.5.2.
Since $X\in {\rm Lie}(H)$, we have $(d\theta)(X)\cdot t=\lambda t$ for some $\lambda\in k$,
and we have $\lambda=0$ since $(d\theta)(X)$ is nilpotent.
Now it follows from Theorem 2 that 
$$\theta(\exp(X))\cdot t=\exp((d\theta)(X))\cdot t=t,$$
and therefore, $\exp(X)\in H(k)$, which proves Theorem 1.

*Proof of Theorem 2.*  Let $A$ be a Lie group over $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $k={\mathbb{C}}$.
As usual, for $X\in{\rm Lie}(A)$ we define the exponential map  $Z(s)=\exp(sX)\in A$
as the solution of the differential equation
$\frac{d}{ds} Z(s)=X\cdot Z(s)$ with initial condition $Z(0)=1_A$.
Then for $A={\rm GL}(V)$ the exponential map is defined by the convergent series above.
If $\phi\colon A\to B$ is a homomorphism of Lie groups,
then the following diagram commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{\rm Lie}(A) @>{d\phi}>> {\rm Lie}(B);\\
@V{\exp_A}VV @VV{\exp_B}V \\
A @>{\phi}>> B;
\end{CD}
$$
Indeed, both composite maps are solutions of the same differential equation with the same initial condition.

Note that the algebraic groups ${\rm GL}(V)$ and ${\rm GL}(W^{\le N})$
and the homomorphism $\theta=\theta^{\le N}$ are all defined  over ${\mathbb{Q}}$.
We use the idea of the Lefschetz principle.
We consider the finitely generated field $l={\mathbb{Q}}(x_{ij})$,
where $x_{ij}\in k$ for  $1\le i,j\le n$ are the matrix elements of $X$.
We embed $l$ into ${\mathbb{C}}$.
We obtain that
$$\exp((d\theta)(X))=\theta(\exp(X))$$
over ${\mathbb{C}}$. Since $X$ and $(d\theta)(X)$ are nilpotent, the expressions in the formula above
are actually polynomials of $(d\theta)(X)$ and $X$, respectively. This completes the proof of Theorem 2.

Comment: Thanks so much Mikhail.  Just a couple points of clarification:

1) The representation $\theta:H \rightarrow \text{Aut}(T(V^*))$.  What you mean is, for $h \in H$, $f \in V^*$, and $v \in V$,

$ \theta(h)(f)(v) = f(hv)$

and then extend to $T(V^*)$ in the obvious manner.  Correct?

2) Is the identity $\theta(\text{exp}(X)) = \text{exp}((d \theta)(X))$ as obvious as it looks?  I don't immediately see it (probably because I'm not used to thinking about differentials).

Thanks again.

Comment: Mikhail, with your permission I'd like to use this proof in a paper I'm about to submit (with attribution of course).  Do you see any problem with this working in positive characteristic?  Again, we can assume that both the series $\text{exp}(X)$ and $\text{log}(g)$ are defined, since we are assuming that $X$ and $g-1$ are both nilpotent of order $\leq n \leq p$.

Comment: Dear Mike, yes, you may use this proof in your paper. Do use the last version, it is correct and not that long. Unfortunately, I cannot deal with the case of positive characteristic. The reason is that we may not assume that $((d\theta)(X))^n=0$, and I cannot control the big  powers of $(d\theta)(X)$. I will keep thinking.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, since you can increase $n$ to a $p$-power, is it really illegal to assume that $((\mathrm d\theta)(X))^n = 0$?

Comment: @LSpice: I use $\exp((d\theta)(X))$, and in characteristic $p$ the expression $\frac{1}{p!}((d\theta)(X))^p$ is not defined.

Comment: @LSpice: Ok, I can compute explicitly the representation $d\theta$ of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and define $\frac{1}{p!}((d\theta)(X))^p$. Howewer, at the moment I cannot prove that if $(d\theta)(X)\cdot t=0$, then $\frac{1}{p!}((d\theta)(X))^p\cdot t=0$, which I need in order to show that $\exp((d\theta)(X))\cdot t=t$ and hence, $\theta(\exp(X))\cdot t=t$.

Comment: @MikeCrumley: You write: "If it makes a difference, I'm actually only interested in the case where the defining polynomials of G have integer (perhaps mod p) coefficients". Yes, it does make a difference.

Comment: (cont.) We should assume that our subgroup $H\subset {\rm GL}(n,\mathbb F_p)$ is a good reduction modulo $p$ of some group subscheme $H_{\mathcal O}\subset {\rm GL}_{n,\mathcal O}$, where $\mathcal O=\mathbb Z_{(p)}$, the ring of fractions in $\mathbb Q$  without $p$ in the denominator. We should also assume that our nilpotent matrix $X\in {\rm Lie}(H)$ is the reduction modulo $p$ of some nilpotent matrix $X_{\mathcal O}\in {\rm Lie}(H_{\mathcal O})\subset M_n(\mathcal O)$. I think that under these assumptions I can show that $\exp(X)\in H(\mathbb F_p)$.

Comment: (cont.) This is satisfied  when both $H$ and $X\in{\rm Lie}(H)$ are reductions of something defined over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I've spent some time going over your proof, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but as best I can tell the only point at which you use that $\text{char}(k) = 0$ is so that you can invoke the Lefshetz principle, which allows you to treat just the cases $k = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, which allows you to think of $Z(s) = \text{exp}(sX)$ as the unique solution to the (analytic) differential equation

$\frac{d}{ds} Z(s) = X Z(s) \qquad  Z(0) = \text{id}$

Comment: But this is also true in characteristic $p > 0$, so long as we insist $Z(s)$ be a polynomial of degree less than $p$, and we replace "analytic" derivative with "formal" derivative of polynomials (that is, we define the derivative of a polynomial via the power rule).  In other words, over fields of characteristic $p >0$, there is exactly one polynomial of degree $\leq p$ which (formally) satisfies $\frac{d}{ds} Z(s) = X Z(s)$ and $Z(0) = \text{id}$, and it is precisely the polynomial $\text{exp}(sX)$. 


Does this help at all in extending this result to $\text{char}(k) = p \geq n$?

Comment: Yes, it seems to help, because my calculations show that $((d\theta)(X))^p=0$. But how do you prove the uniqueness?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, see part (3) of lemma 5.3 of

https://storage.googleapis.com/mike_crumley/Publications/Generic%20Representation%20Theory%20of%20the%20Heisenberg%20Group_Communications%20in%20Algebra.pdf

There's nothing special about $X,Y$ and $Z$ here, the $M_i$ in definition 5.2 can be any matrices over $k$.

Comment: (cont.) I should make a clarification here.  In Lemma 5.3, two polynomials are considered "the same" if they have exactly the same coefficients.  This isn't always tantamount to saying that they are the same as functions.  For instance, the polynomials $f(t) = t^2 - t$ and $f(t) = 0$ define the same function on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  But, this complication can't happen in degree $n < p$, since the only way an $n^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial can by zero on all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is if all of it's coefficients are zero (if any of it's coefficients are non-zero, it can have at most $n < p$ roots).

Comment: (cont.) See also part (1) of lemma 5.5.  There we do actually use that $X$ is nilpotent of order $\leq p$.  And you can replace "dimension of $X$" with "nilpotent order of $X$".

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I think all will work in char. p. We need only the following assertion: If $X^p=0$, then $((d\theta)(X))^p=0$. I will type the proof in the coming days.

Comment: Note that my reference to Springer's book is not quite correct. We need the representation in the space $W$ of all tensors of type $(p,q)$ with $0\le p,q\le N$. I will edit the proof in the coming days.

Comment: $(d\theta)(X)$ would be the image of a Lie algebra element $X$ under the representation $d \theta :\text{Lie}(G) \rightarrow \text{End}(V)$ associated to a representation $\theta:G \rightarrow \text{Aut}(V)$, correct?

Comment: (cont.) If that is the case, then if I'm thinking of $d \theta$ correctly, it is actually the restriction to $\text{Lie}(G) \subset \text{Dist}(G)$ of an algebra representation $d\theta:\text{Dist}(G) \rightarrow \text{End}(V)$.  Then if $X \in \text{Lie}(G) \subset \text{Dist}(G)$ satisfies $X^p = 0$ (which all $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$ happen to satisfy when $G$ is unipotent), does it not automatically follow that $((d \theta)(X))^p = d\theta(X^p) = 0$?

Comment: I don't think it is "automatically" in char. 0, but it is automatically in char p, because in char. p the differential of any homomorphism of algebraic groups preserves the p-operation. (I must think about this.)

Comment: What is ${\rm Dist}(G)$?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi It's the distribution algebra of $G$ (to a large extent what this paper is about).  I'm going to e-mail you some notes on it soon explaining what I'm talking about.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi E-mail sent, please let me know if you didn't get it.

Comment: I don't think this proof works, because $\theta ( \exp_{<p} (X))$ is not necessarily a polynomial of degree $<p$. Indeed when we take the tensor product of $n$ maps each defined by a polynomial of degree $d$, we get a polynomial of degree $nd$. In particular I think theorem $3$ is false in the case $n=2$, $X$ the standard nilpotent, $r=p,s=0$ as the $\theta( \exp_{<p} (X))$ sends $e_2 \otimes \dots e_2$ to a sum of vectors including $e_1 \otimes \dots e_1$ while $\exp_{<p}(\theta(X))$ does not.

Comment: Also I think the statement is wrong, because of the group parameterized by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t & t^p \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Indeed, Theorem 3 is false....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, Thank you for your help in investigating this Mikhail.  Sorry to have wasted your time, I should have caught this earlier.  If I manage to salvage anything out of this I'll let you know.

Comment: @MikeCrumley: Yes, it is possible to salvage something, see my question in comments to Will's answer, and his comment.

Answer (score 1):

In characteristic $p>0$ you can expect a property of this kind in nice situations with certain precautions.

First precaution is that a Lie subalgebra ${\mathfrak g} \leq Lie (GL_n)$ may be tangent to several distinct connected algebraic subgroups. This is brilliantly explored by Will Sawin in his answer.

In practice, your ${\mathfrak g}$ and $G$ are often God given, i.e., they are stabilizers of a $k$-tensor $t$ on $V$. Then you will have your desired exponential and logarithm as soon as you have a second precaution: you need to require $X^{p/k}=0$ or $(1-g)^{p/k}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a reasonable way to prove this result in characteristic 0 is to use the standard Lie group/Lie algebra argument, but to use the algebraic exponential function as defined in Demazure-Gabriel Groupes algebriques to supplement the explicit version used in the question.