# Showing subgroups with equal Lie algebras are equal

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field.  It might as well be algebraically closed, but I do not want to assume that it has characteristic $0$.  I will write "group" for "affine group scheme over $k$", not assuming smoothness.

Two groups can have the same Lie algebras without being equal.  For example, if $k$ has characteristic $2$, then every maximal torus in $\operatorname{SL}_2$ has the same Lie algebra as the centre $\mu_2$.  Even two smooth groups can have the same Lie algebras without being equal:  for example, all maximal tori in $\operatorname{SL}_2$ have the same Lie algebra.  At least it is true that, if a smooth group $H$ is contained in a connected group $G$, and their Lie algebras are equal, then $H$ equals $G$; and so, if two connected subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$ have equal Lie algebras *and* smooth intersection, then they are equal.

I'm looking more for a result in line with [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6), Theorem 13.18(4)(d):  given a maximal torus $T$ in a smooth, *reductive* group $G$, and a root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $G$, there is a unique smooth, connected subgroup of $G$ that is normalised by $T$ and whose Lie algebra is the $\alpha$-weight space of $T$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$.  The key ingredients here are reductivity and the torus action.

So I'm interested in any more general results of this sort that allow one to deduce equality of groups from equality of their Lie algebras.  If that's too broad, I'll focus a bit:  suppose that $G$ is a smooth, reductive group; $H_1$ and $H_2$ are smooth, connected, reductive subgroups; and $T$ is a torus in $H_1 \cap H_2$ that is not necessarily maximal in $G$, but is maximal in both $H_1$ and $H_2$.  In this setting, if the Lie algebras of $H_1$ and $H_2$ are equal, then can we conclude that the groups are equal?

EDIT:  I forgot to add, in case it helps, that, in my situation, $\operatorname C_G(T)^\circ$ (the connectedness automatic if $G$ itself is connected) is a torus.

Comment: I suggest the following question, that seems to be equivalent to yours: Let $U,\,U'$ be two 1-dimensional unipotent subgroups in a smooth connected reductive group $G$. Assume that ${\rm Lie\,}U={\rm Lie\,}U'$. Does it follow that $U=U'$? In char. 0 the answer is Yes...(I have no intuition in positive characteristic.)

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I agree [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930225_368659) question is natural.  It is clear that it would suffice, but not clear to me that it is equivalent to mine.  (I think that the torus action has got to play some role.)  I originally hoped the torus action would be enough:  if $T$ acts with "large orbits" on $U$ and $U'$, then it acts so on $U \cap U'$, so it must be smooth, right?—but it isn't.  (The group often called $\alpha_p$, the $p$th-order neighbourhood of the identity, has such a torus action.)

Comment: However, in line with @MikhailBorovoi's [ideas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930225_368659), a reduction in the spirit of Borel's proof may be applied:  by considering a fixed root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}\Lie(H_1) = \Lie(H_2)$ and working inside $\operatorname C_G(\ker(\alpha)^\circ)$, we may assume that $H_1$ and (therefore) $H_2$ have semisimple rank $1$.

Comment: The answer to [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930225_368659) is No, see [this answer of Will Sawin](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327519/4149).

Comment: In char 0 two perfect connected groups with isomorphic Lie algebras are quotients of a common one by finite central subgroups.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930233_368659)!  So I guess one natural approach, though not necessarily the only one, is to see if one can construct a counterexample to my question in the spirit of @‍WillSawin's elegant counterexample (i.e., intentionally incorporating "Frobenius garbage", in @‍MikeCrumley's [memorable phrasing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930236_368659)).

Comment: @YCor, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930236_368659)!  Here the Lie algebras are not just isomorphic but equal.  I think that my question is trivial (and the answer is 'yes') in characteristic $0$.

Comment: Indeed sorry I didn't read carefully. Possibly it would help writing "subgroups" instead of "groups" in the title.

Comment: @YCor, that is a good [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-groups-are-equal-using-lie-algebras#comment930239_368659).  I have done so.

Comment: 1st try at counterexample using [construction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930233_368659) pointed out by @MikhailBorovoi failed: consider $G = \operatorname{GL}_3$, $T = \operatorname{diag}(1, t, t^p)$, with positive root group $U_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & u & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $H_1$ and $U_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & u & u^p \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $H_2$.  Problem: $U_2$ isn't obviously root subgroup of an $\operatorname{SL}_2$.

Comment: [2nd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930246_368659) try using [construction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930233_368659) pointed out by @MikhailBorovoi failed:  consider $G = \operatorname{GL}_4$, $H_1 = \operatorname{GL}_2$ embedded in the upper left-hand corner, $H_2 = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A^{[p]} \end{pmatrix}$.  Problem: equal Lie algebras, but not common maximal torus; $H_1$ can't be fattened to have exactly that torus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Cent{C}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}$The key point is not, as I expected, whether $\Cent_G(T)^\circ$ is a torus, but whether it equals $\Cent_G(\Lie(T))^\circ$.  Certainly it is contained in the latter group, so this is the same as asking whether $T$ centralises $\Cent_G(\Lie(T))^\circ$.

If we do not require this, then we may adapt a [construction](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327519) by @WillSawin, [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930233_368659) by @MikhailBorovoi, to give a counterexample that is quite close to the one I [attempted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930254_368659) in the comments.  Specifically, we give connected, reductive subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G = \GL_4$ that contain a common maximal torus $T$ (for which $\Cent_G(T)^\circ$ is itself a maximal torus in $G$), and satisfy $\Lie(H_1) = \Lie(H_2)$, but $H_1 \ne H_2$.  Namely, let $t$ be any non-scalar diagonal matrix in $\GL_2$, and put $H_1 = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} g & 0 \\ 0 & g^{[p]} \end{pmatrix} \mathrel\colon g \in \GL_2\right\}$ and $H_2 = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} g & 0 \\ 0 & t g^{[p]}t^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \mathrel\colon g \in \GL_2\right\}$, where $g^{[p]}$ is the matrix obtained by raising every entry of $g$ to the $p$th power.

Next we prove that, if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are connected, reductive subgroups of a common group $G$ that contain a common maximal torus $T$, and satisfy $\Lie(H_1) = \Lie(H_2)$, *and if in addition* $T$ centralises $\Cent_G(\Lie(T))^\circ$, then $H_1$ must equal $H_2$.  As [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal#comment930225_368659) by @MikhailBorovoi, it suffices to show that, for every root $b$ of $T$ in $\Lie(H_1) = \Lie(H_2)$, the corresponding root subgroups of $b$ in $H_1$ and $H_2$ are equal.  Let $\mathfrak u$ be the common $b$-root subspace of $\Lie(H_1) = \Lie(H_2)$.  Then we have $T$-equivariant isomorphisms $e_{i\,b} \colon \mathfrak u \to H_i$ such that $\Ad(e_{i\,b}(X))Y$ equals $Y - \mathrm db(Y)X$ for all $X \in \mathfrak u$ and all $Y \in \Lie(T)$.  That is, $e_{1\,b}(X)e_{2\,b}(X)^{-1}$ lies in $\Cent_G(\Lie(T))$ for all $X \in \mathfrak u$, and hence, since $\mathfrak u$ is connected, in $\Cent_G(\Lie(T))^\circ$.  Since this group is centralised by $T$, we see upon conjugating $e_{1\,b}(X)e_{2\,b}(X)^{-1}$ by $t$ that it equals $e_{1\,b}(b(t)X)e_{2\,b}(b(t)X)^{-1}$, for all $X \in \mathfrak u$ and all $t \in T$.  In particular, $e_{1\,b}(X)e_{2\,b}(X)^{-1}$, as a function of $X$, is constant on $\mathfrak u \setminus \{0\}$, and hence, since it is continuous, is constant on $\mathfrak u$; but its value at $X = 0$ is the identity.

Comment: Could you please state explicitly, what assertions you prove or disprove in the second and third paragraphs of your answer?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal/368772#comment930653_368772) for the suggestion.  I have tried to make it clearer.

Comment: You write: " Then we have isomorphisms $e_{i\,b} \colon \mathfrak u \to H_i$ such that ${\rm Ad}(e_{i\,b}(X))Y$ equals $Y - \mathrm db(Y)X$ for all $X \in \mathfrak u$ and all $Y \in {\rm Lie}(T)$".  What are these isomorphisms $e_{i\,b}$ ?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [they](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal/368772#comment930691_368772) are the automorphisms coming from a choice of Chevalley basis (see [Carter - Simple groups of Lie type, p. 64](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Simple_Groups_of_Lie_Type/nW9tPZUMkdIC?gbpv=1&pg=PA64)).  They are defined at first over $\mathbb Z$, so make sense over any field.  *A priori* they exist only on the adjoint group, but the adjoint-quotient map is an isomorphism on unipotent subgroups, so they may be lifted uniquely to $H_i$.

Comment: Could you please add details to the following sentence? "Since this group is centralised by $T$, we have that $e_{1\,b}(b(t)X)e_{2\,b}(b(t)X)^{-1}$ equals $e_{1\,b}(X)e_{2\,b}(X)^{-1}$ for all $X \in \mathfrak u$ and all $t \in T$."

Comment: To see [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal/368772?noredirect=1#comment930887_368772), just act by $T$.  (Ah, the point is that the isomorphisms are $T$-equivariant.  This follows from the explicit construction in [Carter](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Simple_Groups_of_Lie_Type/nW9tPZUMkdIC?gbpv=1&pg=PA61) (see [my reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368659/showing-subgroups-with-equal-lie-algebras-are-equal/368772?noredirect=1#comment930787_368772)).  I will add that.)

Comment: The proof looks correct! What is ${\rm C}_G(T)^\circ$ in your counter-example?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, $\operatorname C_G(T)^\circ = \operatorname C_G(T)$ in my counterexample is a maximal torus (the standard diagonal torus in $G = \operatorname{GL}_4$), whereas $\operatorname C_G(\operatorname{Lie}(T))^\circ = \operatorname C_G(\operatorname{Lie}(T))$ is $\operatorname C_G(T)^\circ\cdot(1 \times \operatorname{GL}_2)$.